# MySQL Prepare -> Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, prepare

I've been trying to figure out why this gives me an error:

```
PREPARE test FROM 'SELECT t.blah FROM (SELECT ? AS blah) t;';
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.blah' in 'field list'

also:

```
PREPARE test FROM 'SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT ? AS blah) t;';
```

> ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 't'

It would be great if someone could shed some light on these errors..Thanks!!

**EDIT: There is a bug report here:** http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71577

Seems like the workaround would be to do:

```
PREPARE test FROM 'SELECT t.blah FROM (SELECT ? AS blah UNION SELECT ? AS blah) t;';
```

Comment: I don't really see the use case for such a statement, but I see the difficulty to discriminate between a placeholder for a value (allowed) and a placeholder for a column (not allowed).

Comment: In the example above the placeholders are for values, not columns. These are allowed and it is an accepted bug (see link above). I intentionally simplified the question so it illustrates the concept and makes it easy to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BoynanPenev First, before your edit with link to the bug report I assumed you would use placeholders for column names, but after reading the bug report realized that it should be constant values.

Comment: So we agree it's a bug then? :)

Comment: I do, I commented about the difficulty to discriminate both. But at a second look, if there's no `FROM` clause, it's got to be a value and not a column.

Comment: This was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124682/unknown-column-in-field-list-when-prepared-statements-placeholder-is-in-sub/32127450#32127450

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use :

```
PREPARE test FROM 'SELECT ? AS blah';
```

Your workaround gives a different result.

Comment: I need it for: insert into f(id,a,b,c) select id,a,b,c from (select ? as id, ? as a, ? as b, ? as c) t where not exists(select 1 from f where f.id = t.id and f.tstamp >= t.tstamp) on duplicate key update a = t.a, b = t.b, c = t.c; in a prepared statement.. The workaround gives correct results if you do a few row by row inserts..well in my case.

Comment: UNION between two identical selects: SELECT 'a' as a UNION select 'a' as a will give you the same result. Could you please elaborate on how this can produce a different result???